# Memory growth when using DispatchQueue. Instruments shows growth in non-object objects

Tags: ios, swift, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

The memory of my app (navigation app) keeps on growing until iOS kills it sooner or later. I was able to pinpoint the problem to the use of a custom DispatchQueue in a timer target function that fires every second. (i.e. while navigating a timer is running that fires every second and executes the `updateUI` function below.)

This is an extract of the viewcontroller:

```
class NavViewController: UIViewController, ... {
    ...

    let processLocationUpdateQeue = DispatchQueue(label: "processLocationUpdateQeue", qos: .userInteractive)
    var updateUITimer: Timer!
    ...

    func startNav() {
        ...
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] (_) -> Void in
            self.updateUITimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(NavViewController.updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
        ...
    }

    func updateUI() {
        let freeDrive = self.isFreeDrive ?? false
        processLocationUpdateQeue.async { [unowned self] in
            self.totalBreakTimeInclCurrentBreak = self.totalBreakTimeInSec
            if !self.takingBreak {
                if self.timeOfLastPositionUpdate != nil && self.timeOfLastPositionUpdate.secondsAgo() >= 90 {
                     // some code that's not being executed during my analyses of this problem
                }
            }
            else {
                self.totalBreakTimeInclCurrentBreak = self.totalBreakTimeInSec + Float((self.breakStartTime ?? Date()).secondsAgo())
                if ((self.autoResumeSwitch != nil && self.autoResumeSwitch!.isOn) || self.autoResumeSwitch == nil) && self.breakStartCoordinate?.distance(from: lastKnownLocation.coordinate.toCLLocation()) > 100 {
                     // some code that's not being executed during my analyses of this problem
                }
            }

            self.avgSpeedMperS = min(self.maxSpeedMperS,self.coveredDistanceInMeters/(Float(self.tripStartTime.secondsAgo())-self.totalBreakTimeInclCurrentBreak))
            if freeDrive && UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
                // app is running in background for my analyses, so the code here doesn't get executed
            }
        }
    }

}
```

When I run my app using Instruments allocations tool I see the memory growing. Most (in fact all) of the growth is in non-object and the stack trace points to the `updateUI` function. See this screenshot:
[image]
Note the trace step just after (above) the step where the function is called. It's something with DispatchQueue.

I've been analysing this for 2 days now, tried a bunch of things. Here's what I know at this point:

- **Memory does not grow** if I take the code out of `processLocationUpdateQeue.async {}` and run it on the main queue.
- Wrapping the code inside `processLocationUpdateQeue.async {}` into `autoreleasepool {}` doesn't help
- Using `processLocationUpdateQeue = DispatchQueue(label: "processLocationUpdateQeue", qos: .userInteractive, attributes: [], autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem, target: nil)` (note the .workItem) doesn't help.
- I'm using `[unowned self]` so retain cycle is not the problem (I think)??
- I tried using `[weak self]`, same problem.
- I tried `DispatchQueue(label: "processLocationUpdateQeue", qos: .userInteractive).async {}` instead of using the class let `processLocationUpdateQeue`, same problem
- Simulating a memory warning doesn't 'clean' the growth
- The memory graph debugger doesn't show any leaks

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
So, this is interesting. I only see this when my app is running in the background. Also, when I bring my app to the foreground the related non-objects that were built up while backgrounded, disappear !!!

Comment: If you remove all the if-else statements does it still leak?

Comment: Yes. If I remove everything inside processLocationUpdateQeue.async {} it still leaks, but if I take everything out of the processLocationUpdateQeue and run it on the main queu it doesn't leak.

Comment: Added how I initialise the timer. It's initialised in the startNav() function which can be called from several other functions, mostly from viewDidLoad though.

Comment: Just to add... when I run it on the main queue I also comment out theprocessLocationupdateQueu.async line. So it's definitely something with this queue. I don't think it's the code inside.

Comment: Why is the timer created on the main queue? That doesn't do anything because Timers use the current run-loop and not the current thread-queue. In other words, you don't need: `DispatchQueue.main.async ` to create the timer.

Comment: OK. Not that familiar with runloops. So you're saying I can leave it out? I did this on purpose so that I can also invalidate the timer on the main queue. (I read somewhere that you need to invalidate it on the same queue as you initialise it)

Comment: `[unowned self]` will crash the App if `NavController` closes but the closure is still queued and therefore executed _after_ `NavController` is closed.